# URL available in urls.py still getting 404 in Django 2

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I wrote a function in `views.py` as follows

```py
def removeinvoices(request,invoiceID,creatorID,deletorid,typeofchange):
    form = invoicestorageForm()
    form.invoiceid = invoiceID
    form.creatorid = creatorID
    form.deletorid = deletorid
    form.typeofchange = typeofchange
    form.save()
    thatInvoice = taxInvoice.objects.filter(invoiceid=invoiceID).first()
    thatInvoice.delete()
    messages.success(request, "Invoice ID "+ invoiceID +" removed Successfully !")
    return redirect("vieweinvoices")
```

and wrote in `urls.py` as follows:

```
path("removeinvoices/<int:invoiceID>/<int:creatorID/><int:deletorid>/<str:typeofchange>", views.removeinvoices, name="removeinvoices",)
```

And I'm generating the href in JS dynamically, I'm able to get all variables coorectly, but is still says **404 error** when I click on href 
[image]

I'm able to work fine with all other URLs mentioned in image.

Not sure where I'm going wrong!

Comment: I assume you have an issue in the link. As I can see you have /removeinvoices/5/1/1/'delete'/. Check parameter <str:typeofchange>, url 'delete'/ looks strange.

Comment: /removeinvoices/5/1/1/delete - tried this as well :P

Comment: Of course you will have an issue, because browser can't understand 'delete'/. And Django can't understand 'delete'/ !== delete/.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:9091/removeinvoices/5/1/1/delete/ this is also throwing the same error budy

Comment: try <typeofchange> instead of <str:typeofchange>

Comment: Yup tried that as well     path("removeinvoices/<int:invoiceID>/<int:creatorID/><int:deletorid>/<typeofchange>/", views.removeinvoices, name="removeinvoices",),

Comment: You have misplaced on `/` between `<int:creatorID/><int:deletorid>`.

Answer (score 0):

To use `str` in `Path` you can use [`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path)

**urls.py**  using `re_path()`

```
re_path(r"^removeinvoices/(?P<invoiceID>\d+)/(?P<creatorID>\d+)/(?P<deletorid>\d+)/(?P<typeofchange>\w+)/$", views.removeinvoices, name="removeinvoices",)
```

URL: http://127.0.0.1:9091/5/1/1/delete/

Also, in your url, you have misplaced on `/` between `<int:creatorID/><int:deletorid>`.

**Change:**

```
path("removeinvoices/<int:invoiceID>/<int:creatorID/><int:deletorid>/<str:typeofchange>", views.removeinvoices, name="removeinvoices",)
```

**To:**

```
path("removeinvoices/<int:invoiceID>/<int:creatorID>/<int:deletorid>/<str:typeofchange>", views.removeinvoices, name="removeinvoices",)
```

Comment: Try with `re_path()`